# If statement to move HTML element

Tags: jquery

I have a search bar that I can't recreate. It can only be moved. I can easily move it with this statement:

```
$('#containerTBRight').insertBefore('search2');
```

The problem is that I need that statement to work on every other page and the one below to work on certain links.

```
$('#containerTBRight').insertBefore('search2');
```

I created this `if` statement but for some reason I am not getting the desired result. Is this the right way to do this?

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://support.com/support/default.asp' 
    || window.location.href == 'http://support.com/support/default.asp?pg=pgOldMainMenu' 
    || window.location.href == 'http://support.com/support/default.asp#') {
    $('#containerTBRight').insertBefore('search1');
}
else {
    $('#containerTBRight').insertBefore('search2');
}
```

Comment: thanks @Rory McCrossan

Comment: WOW so stupid i just saw it.... that @george

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to that page where you need to execute the else block and then easily write the if condition as follows. Assuming that you add a class `exception` to `body` tag of that page.

```
if ($('body').hasClass('exception')) {
    $('#containerTBRight').insertBefore('search2');
}
else {
    $('#containerTBRight').insertBefore('search1');
}
```

This should work.